# How do I setup a window Icon using Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, icons, macos-catalina, python-3.8, .ico

I'm trying to set up a window Icon so it would appear right next to the name of a dictionary I'm doing. When I run the code, I get the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Latin_app/windows.py", line 20, in <module>
    window.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='/Users/sergioley-languren/home/Latin_app/Logo.jpeg'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "/Users/sergioley-languren/Latin_app/Logo.jpeg"
```

When I tried to use the `iconbitmap` tkinter function with the .jpeg file converted to a .ico picture, it worked, but I got a blank page icon instead. The code below is the problematic code:

```
### Imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from pathlib import Path

##Extra Code
home = print(Path.home())
### Application screen code
window = Tk()

##Frame
frame1 = Frame(window)
frame1.pack()

## Window Title
window.title("Latin Unit 1 Dictionary - Based on Orion Academy Latin I , Unit 1")
window.geometry('1110x950')

#App Icon
window.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='/Users/sergioley-languren/home/Latin_app/Logo.jpeg'))

## Window Main Loop
window.mainloop()
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it? 
(If it helps, I'm using MacOs Catilina.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tkinter.PhotoImage` only support `GM, PPM, GIF, PNG` image.Your image is `JPEG`,for sure it will raise Exception.

There are some solutions,but the direct way is to change the image extension to `ico` and use `iconbitmap()`

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(r"xxx.jpeg") # your jpeg image path
img.save(r"Icon.ico")
```

This will generate a new `ico` image in your current path.

Then you can use `iconbitmap('Icon.ico')` directly.

Comment: Python can't find PIL it gives me an error when I try to do the first line.

Comment: @SergioLey-Languren so you should use `pip install pillow` to install it.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Logo.jpeg'```. How would you fix this?

Comment: check the path.You path maybe should be "Logo.jpg".

Comment: it wasn't and I changed it but now this is the current error: ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Logo.jpg'```

Comment: file='/Users/sergioley-languren/home/Latin_app/Logo.jpeg'),This is path in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This works to set icon for Tkinter App

```
from tkinter import *
window =Tk()
##set title for window
window.title("Tkinter App")
##set window icon  
window.iconphoto(False,PhotoImage(file='logo.png'))
window.mainloop()
```