# Why ico image does not display on the window using Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, ico

For at least some example I took one of the images from [here](https://www.iconarchive.com/tag/ico-files) and downloaded as ico file to set to the icon in Tkinter using the following code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('icon appears!')

root.iconbitmap('Custom-Icon-Design-Flatastic-3-Filetype-ico.ico')


root.mainloop()
```

However, for some reason, it does not display on the window. Interestingly, if I drag the window icon to my desktop, it takes ico file which should display, but it does not:(

I have tried numerous ico images, but it seems that the problem is somewhere else. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664217/how-do-i-setup-a-window-icon-using-tkinter) question and even tried to convert png with PIL to ico. Still, nothing displays...

Running on python 3.7, macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4.

What may be the problem?

Comment: is your `.ico` file in the same directory as ur `.py` file?

Comment: @CoolCloud yes. There is no pathing problem :(

Comment: have u tried a diff ico file?

Comment: @CoolCloud As I have stated in the question I have tried numerous ico files. Converted from png, using PIL or some online converters.. ico file appears in the icon, it is not displaying

Comment: the default, leaf is being displayed?

Comment: [set-tkinter-icon-on-mac-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826692/set-tkinter-icon-on-mac-os) may help.

Comment: @CoolCloud no, i see the file icon which is usually displayed by Preview utility on Mac (for pdfs for example). If rightclick it, I see the name of the ico file

Comment: this might be a bug with mac os x? everything with ur code is pretty fine tho

Comment: @acw1668 probably should work

Comment: oh wait ur on a mac ? macs too use .ico? im not sure the configurations with mac

Comment: @acw1668 tried setting icns, still does not work for some reason

Comment: Sorry I don't have Mac machine, so I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file='logo.gif'))
```

Where logo.gif is file name. I've done it with `.gif` extension maybe it'll accept other extensions like `.png, .jpg, .jpeg` ...etc

Comment: It works. I can see the Icon in the toolbar but not in the window... Can you maybe elaborate what this line does?

Comment: Where do you want to display that icon ?   You can read [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter/) what does it means

Comment: Thanks. This sound like a fix for Mac.